# Auto zooming the map control

Tags: windows-phone-8, maps

When we display a Map control on Windows Phone 8, and we display a MapRoute, is there any way to auto set the zoom level so the full route first?

Comment: If you have "Route" instead of "MapRoute", you can use "BoundingBox".

Comment: But how do I convert that bounding box to a zoom level?

Comment: yourMapControl.SetView(route.BoundingBox)

Comment: Ah, thanks! Do you want to put that as an answer so I mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have "Route" instead of "MapRoute", you can use "BoundingBox".

```
yourMapControl.SetView(route.BoundingBox)
```

Comment: As an additional note, that only works after the map is displayed, if it's right after you construct and display the map, it has no effect

Answer (score 4):

To auto-zoom the map in c# with a list of coordinates (instead of a route), you can auto-generate a view by using the following:

```
//Adjust zoom
LocationRectangle lr = 
   LocationRectangle.CreateBoundingRectangle(myGeoCoordinate, incidentGeoCoordinate, [and more]);
myMap.SetView(lr);
```

Comment: this method is awsome

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to say "zoom to include points A,B & X,Y" but if you know these you could calculate the distance between them and the center point between those outlying points and then center on that point and then set a zoom level which will include the whole area.

Comment: The documentation just says that zoom level is from 1 to 20, and doesn't give any more details, do you what what distance per pixel does each level corresponds to?